# Rails のsimple_formのi18について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

railsのsimpleフォームのラベルのi18化について、下記設定で行ったのですが、
反映されずどなたかご教授頂ければと存じます。

※i18変更後サーバーの再起動は実施しております。

model　パス　　：app/models/article.rb

html 　パス　　：app/views/articles/new.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(@article, url: articles_path) do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.submit "送信"
```

i18　　パス　　：config/locales/simple_form.yml

```
ja:
　　simple_form:
　　　labels:
  　　　article:
    　　　title: 'タイトル'
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/89867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railsんバージョンが分かりませんがlocaleの言語設定変更はしましたでしょうか。

rails5系
http://docs.komagata.org/5355

rails4系

```
config/application.rb
```

の

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

をコメントアウト外してenをjaに変更